# Working with Foreign languages

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, html, utf-8

My DB needs to hold strings containing foreign language characters. As an example, a user enters string into form, the form is submitted and the string is added to DB.  The string will be displayed on a web page. I would like to use UTF-8 as this will be able to handle all of the required languages.

Currently, I believe my DB is set to 'latin1', but webpages are capable of displaying correct characters anyways. Problems arise when trying to set textareas to hold foreign characters and when viewing DB via command-line.

How can I implement this effectively? My plan was to blitz the whole site such that the DB charset is UTF-8, and the web page charset is UTF-8. Could someone give me the minimal commands on how to do this so I don't end up duplicating things (Having "UTF-8" commands everywhere when I really just need one) and making things too difficult to control?

edit: Using MySQL, PHP and JavaScript/HTML

Comment: Your question might be a lot easier to answer if you told which database you are using and maybe also which framework/language the site is written in.

Comment: Assumption of only one "DB" and the disclosure of "latin1" = MySQL

Answer (score 0):

That would be the way to go (UTF-8) in the DB. Here's what you want to look at:

1. Does your browser support UTF-8 characters (make sure the font you use has characters for all of the relevant code pages that you need to support) and is the meta charset tag set correctly?

   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"> (in HTML4)

   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> (In XHTML)
2. Are you sending a ContentType header? If so, make sure it matches what you define in your meta or XML version tag.
3. In regards to your command line, make sure the terminal you're using and your shell's charset also match. (check the locale on your server, assuming it's *NIX you can do this by typing "locale") doing this will change your locale setting:

   export LANG="en_US.UTF-8"

   If you're using windows check the system's locale. http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-vista/Change-the-system-locale . If you're using PuTTY to log into your server, you're going to want to make sure you've set it to unicode mode to support UTF-8.
4. The other thing you're going to want to look at in mysql is the table collation setting. Make sure it's a collation that makes sense for what you're looking to do or indices will have unexpected behaviors. (see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-mysql.html )

More likely than not, you'd want to set up a header file for your website itself that has the characterset encoding information and include that in every view. As far as the DB is concerned, obviously your text and varchar fields need to support the right encoding, there's no simple way to do this without altering each table to make sure its individual charset is right and its collation is right (once a table is created in a charset you need to convert it).